# What is the result of 1 and float on OR gate?

Tags: logic-gates, floating

If only one input is 1 into an OR gate, the output is 1, but does that still count if there is no input from other sources? (like float) Or is the output simply float as well?

Comment: What technology is the gate imlemented in? The answer is different for TTL and CMOS.

Comment: @ThePhoton No idea tbh, this is just a beginner's work. The task involves a 74ls16x counter and I'm wondering if I could just connect multiple outputs together into one input without any gates and have it work to count from 33 to 51, then from 88 to 151  and 215 to 220, rinse an repeat. So just AND ing the binary for 51 and 151 and plugging it all up to the clear or enable inputs?

Comment: The 74LS series is TTL.

Comment: @ChinguunErdenebadrakh, your question asks about a gate with a floating input, but now your comment says you're more interested in whether you can connect outputs to each other? That's a totally different question. (And the answer is, unless your gates have open-collector outputs, you should not connect the outputs of TTL gates together)

Comment: Leaving inputs floating is bad engineering practice and can lead to unpredictable behaviour. It’s better to connect an unused input to a known logic level.

Comment: @ChinguunErdenebadrakh What you are hinting towards is the infamous [3-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) family of gates. I've been looking for some of those, myself. ;)

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the output of an OR gate will be High (1) if any number of inputs are High,

If a "floating" input happens to float High, the output will be High regardless of any other inputs.