# Output of a logic gate when its inputs are floating

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

As per [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502283/347018) answer, the output of an OR gate when one of its inputs is 1 is 1 regardless of the other inputs, even if they are floating/disconnected.

However, what is the output of an OR gate when both of its inputs are disconnected or floating somewhere between 0 & 1?

Also, what is its output when one of its inputs is valid 0 and the other input is disconnected or floating somewhere between 0 & 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output depends on logic type.

For a TTL chip an unconnected floating input tends to be high.

For a CMOS chip an unconnected floating input could be anything, even change state from any received electromagnetic interference, nearby mains wiring or RF signals from mobile phones and laptops.

So generally the input would be undefined and so will the output.

The output could be anything, including halfway between logic 0 and 1, or the chip could be damaged by current due to halfway voltages.

Answer (score 1):

The output is undefined.  Could be 1, could be 0, could be oscillating between the two, could change based on a little bit of noise somewhere.  That's why the guidance is to tie unused inputs high or low, to prevent excessive power consumption in the oscillation or in-between case and possible interference with other gates on the chip.